# Is there a way to find the point of intersection of two quadratic Bezier curves?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quadratics, graphing-functions, bezier-curve, intersection-theory

Each Bezier curve have two quadratic parametric equations to express the curve.

Can these be utilised to find the point of intersection with the other curve? If so, how? I am really confused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compute the points of intersection.

Several techniques for doing this are described in chapter 7 of [these notes](https://scholarsarchive.byu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=facpub#page99). Some of them are algebraic, and some iterative/numerical.

Basically, you have to find the zeros of a polynomial of degree 4. This is to be expected, since there will generally be four points of intersection.